# Ubuntu 16.04 boot loader corrupt

Tags: magento-1.9, linux

My system is not booting properly as it shows a error on booting
It shows error on booting ERROR=>"Read Error" 
Can anyone provide me solution for this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this you have to use alternative option as this is also happen for me you should boot your system from a usb drive then back your data and if there is problem of boot loader then it will be fixed when you restat after booting.

this works for me try this once.